# using function expression vs function declaration as closure

Tags: javascript

Learning JavaScript patterns. Is there any difference in creating constructor function as expression vs statement. I was reading about closure and that is the reason of return statement in example below.  My questions are :

1)Do either or both functions qualify to be called as constructor function (I have not used this keyword)?

2)Differences between these two approaches.

```
var Dog1 = function (){
var name = 'xyz';
return {
    sayname: function(){
        console.log('name is '+name+'');
    }
}
}

function Dog2(){
var name = 'xyz';
return {
    sayname: function(){
        console.log('name is '+name+'');
    }
}
}

var mydog1 = new Dog1();
var mydog2 = new Dog2();
```

Sorry if my examples look silly!

Comment: Zero difference, but those aren’t constructors in the JavaScript sense, so you shouldn’t use them with `new` or name them with an uppercase first letter.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. It is helpful.